# Which is best way to store image data

Tags: php, android

I have a Web application as well as Andriod app.I want to store the User profile picture in database.Can Anybody Suggest me which is the best and secure way to store image,so that
1. I should be able to access profile picture for the android app.
2. I should be able to retrieve the image for my web application also.

Comment: This link might help you https://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/handling-images-in-webapi/

Comment: try https://github.com/bumptech/glide library to load and cache images.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the base64_encode-function of PHP:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.base64-encode.php

Then save the base64-code to database.

Android (which is Java) is able to decode the base64-Code.

Here is an example:

```
$imageData = file_get_contents('path/to/image');
$base64Image = base64_encode($imageData);

// save base64Image to database
```

Comment: problem in base64 is that I'm using Dropzone.js to upload file.To edit profile picture I'm not able to display the preview in dropzone.